# Kotlin - Copy object property values of one instance to another

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection

I have the following data class in kotlin:

```
data class Test(
    val one: Int?,
    val two: Int?,
    val three: Three?,
){
    
    data class Three(
        val four: Int?,
        val five: Five?,
    ){
        
        data class Five(
            val six: Int?,
            val seven: Int?,
        )
    }
}
```

and a variable to store the instance of this class:

```
val cache: Test = Test()
```

I have another function that returns the instance of "Test" with only some properties set.

```
fun onValueUpdated(newValue: Test){
    // i need to update the value of "cache" here if
    // any of the properties in "newValue" is not null.
    // Eg: if newValue = Test( two = 2 )
    // i need to update "cache" as cache?.two = 2 without affecting other values in cache.
}
```

Is there any method based on reflection that updates value in "cache" based on the "newValue" instead of updating each values manually ?.

```
fun updateCache(newValue: Test, cache: Test){
    //......
    // copy all non-null values from "newValue" to cache (including nested ones)
    // 
}
```

Comment: There are no nested values because your classes don't reference each other. Or did you mean to define those as `inner` classes?

Comment: Are you looking for the `copy` method that's generated automatically on all data classes?

Comment: If I understand your question and we ignore the nested classes, I still don't think this is possible. Once a class is instantiated, there's no way to use reflection to detect which properties were set using the default implementation.

Comment: I just need to copy all the non null values from "newValue" to "cache" without manually copying each property

Answer (score 0):

Nope. If you want to copy non-null values from one instance to another you need to write a method/function that does exactly that. A generic mechanism to do this doesn't exist.

Comment: Is there any method using reflection ?

Comment: No. You would need to write one yourself.